# Can I get the next element in an object array in java by adding 1?

Tags: java, arrays

In the code below:

```
class A {}
A[] arr = new A[10];
A a = arr[2];
A b = a;
```

Can I use `b + 1` like in c++ to get the next element after `b` in the array?

Comment: The short answer is No.

Comment: Could you add the line to show what you mean by using `b+1`?

Comment: Imho, No, you can't do that...array in c++ is treated as pointer, but not in java

Comment: Write and run to see for yourself rather than posting code

Comment: @uba, like c = b + 1;

Comment: @sol4me, sorry, I just began to learn java from c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't . Because in java even an array is treated as object . The variable of that array contains the reference value of the memory in heap containing that object instead of just pointing to the first element of that array itself. So adding 1 to the reference variable of an array gives compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this as operator overloading is not supported in java.